# C - How to give a name to a struct dynamically

Tags: c, object, struct

I am trying to change the number that identifies different structures dynamically (being the last digit of the struct name meant to be the same as the `i` variable).
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char * name;
    char * job;
    int age;
};

int main () {
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    long random = rand() % 20;
    for (int i = 0; i != (random + 1); i++) {
        struct Person strcat("Person", i");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like that for each `i` the struct's name changed. So let's say that `i = 2`. I would like the struct name to be `Person2`.

Is there any way for me to do this in C?

Comment: This does not make a sense. You need to declare an array of objects of the structure type outside the for loop.

Comment: And this line struct Person strcat("Person", i"); does not make a sense.

Comment: An object can have one name. Names only exist in the programmers brain, not in the program. Maybe you have been exposed to SAS?

Comment: The counter-question is: Why do you want to do this, and what does it accomplish? This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It's somewhat common that beginners think it makes sense to name variables dynamically. It doesn't, because variables/identifiers exist for the sole purpose of being convenient names for the _ programmer_. The final executable doesn't contain them and the user doesn't need to know about them. Therefore it simply doesn't make sense to name variables/identifiers in run-time.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. identifiers in C don't change at run-time. In fact, for variables, they generally don't even *exist* at runtime.

As @VladFromMoscow suggests, what you're probably after is an array of `struct Person`'s, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char * name;
    char * job;
    int age;
};

#define MAX_PERSON_NAME_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_NUM_PERSONS 20

int main () {
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    long random = rand() % MAX_NUM_PERSONS;
    struct Person persons[random];

    for (int i = 0; i != (random + 1); i++) {
        persons[i].name = malloc(MAX_PERSON_NAME_LENGTH + 1);
        if (persons[i].name != NULL) {
            sprintf(persons[i].name, "The %d'th person", i);
        }
        else {
            perror("allocating memory for a person name");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    // do something with persons
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, but there's no need for such a function anyway. you can achieve what you want by simply creating an array of structs. So, you will access them by doing Person[0], Person[1] etc.. instead of creating 1 different name for each structure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).